# character encoding in libc?

Tags: c, encoding

What is the character encoding expected in libc? For example, gethostname(char *name, size_t namelen); takes char* as argument. Is it expected that the name parameter be encoded in utf8(which keeps the ascii intact) or plain ascii or some other format?

Also does C mandates any character encoding scheme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All string functions (except widechar ones) support only native charset, e.g. ASCII on Unix/Linux/Windows or EBCDIC on IBM mainframe/midrange computers.

Comment: How do use these functions in non english environment?

Comment: Also, i think libc hasn't got wchar_t* equivalent of all char * functions.

Comment: You have to convert yourself or get some lib to do the job - see more here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313555/light-c-unicode-library.
Anyway you cannot name you host in UTF-8, can you?

Answer (score 1):

- char uses ASCII
- wchar_t is the standard C datatype for unicode

use  and  in order to deal with the wide characters.

Comment: what is encoding used for wchar_t? Is it UCS2 or utf16?

Comment: @chappar: it's implementation-defined.

Comment: Implementation-defined? I thought it was application-defined? (Two apps compiled with the same compiler on the same OS has the right to use different encodings, which is consistent with the "low-levelness" of C.)

Answer (score 0):

`char` should be a 7-bit compatible ASCII encoding (I can't find any definite reference on this though). The [definition of `wchar_t` is left to the implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character), but the C standard requires that the characters from the [C portable character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_character_set) set be the same. If I understand this correctly, then

```
char a = 'a';
wchar_t aw = L'a';
if (a == (char)aw) {
    // should be true
}
```

The standard does not say anything about UTF-8.

Comment: ASCII isn't mandatory, the implementation may use EBCDIC too.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably have to use a third-party library, such as [GLib](http://library.gnome.org/devel/glib/2.20/glib-Character-Set-Conversion.html).
This lib is portable and very useful, it also provides regular expressions, data structures and more.

Comment: Probably because the answer was not helpful. How would GLib help in this case?