# Unicode string normalization in C/C++

Tags: c++, unicode, utf-8, utf-16, unicode-normalization

Am wondering how to normalize strings (containing utf-8/utf-16) in C/C++.
In .NET there is a function [String.Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1.aspx) .

I used UTF8-CPP in the past but it does not provide such a function. 
[ICU](http://site.icu-project.org/) and Qt provide string normalization but I prefer lightweight solutions.

Is there any "lightweight" solution for this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As I wrote in [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313555/light-c-unicode-library/313559#313559), [utf8proc](https://julialang.org/utf8proc/) is a very nice, lightweight, library for basic Unicode functionality, including Unicode string normalization.

Comment: I have problems in visual studio 2010 with utf8proc.
typedef unsigned char bool; -> dosen't compile in C++

Comment: I don't have familiarity with VS 2010, but can't you compile the library as a C library, and link it in that way?

Comment: The problem is in the header file that's why we can't use it even as a static library.
A simple workaround is to replace bool, true, false to _bool, _true, _false occurences.
Example :
typedef unsigned char _bool;
enum {_false, _true};

Comment: Yes, you could probably do that without too much trouble - it isn't a very complicated library. We also had to make one or two minor changes like that.

Comment: The Julia team has an updated fork of utf8proc called libmojibake (https://github.com/JuliaLang/libmojibake) which is updated for Unicode 7 support.  (It also has some other small fixes, e.g. it fixed C++ compatibility.)

Answer (score 4):

For Windows, there is the `NormalizeString()` function (unfortunately for Vista and later only - as far as I see on MSDN):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319093%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

It's the simplest way to go that I have found so far.
I guess it's quite lightweight too.

```
int NormalizeString(
    _In_      NORM_FORM NormForm,
    _In_      LPCWSTR   lpSrcString,
    _In_      int       cwSrcLength,
    _Out_opt_ LPWSTR    lpDstString,
    _In_      int       cwDstLength
);
```

Answer (score 3):

A good UTF-8 solution is glib's [g_utf8_normalize()](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/unstable/glib-Unicode-Manipulation.html#g-utf8-normalize) function. Would require to convert std::wstring to std::string (utf16 to utf8) if you need this for wstring too (which would make it quite an expensive solution, hence I'm looking myself for a better solution, if possible with pure C++(11) means).

Answer (score 2):

You could build ICU with minimal (or possibly, no other data- I think all of the normalization data is now internal), and then statically link. I haven't tried this recently, but I believe the total size is pretty small in that case.

Answer (score 1):

"Lightweight" in your context means "with limited functionality". I would use ICU source as an example, and reference http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/ to implement this "lightweight" functionality.