# Is there String.Normalize() alternative in WinRT?

Tags: windows-8, windows-runtime

Is there any alternative to string.Normalize() in WinRT? I want to simply remove accents from input strings using [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4046937/removing-diacritics-in-silverlight-string-normalize-issue), but I cannot find anywhere this method in WinRT.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've discovered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/249087/how-do-i-remove-diacritics-accents-from-a-string-in-net) quick and short solution, that works just fine in WinRT:

```cs
public static string RemoveAccents(this string accentedStr)
{
    byte[] tempBytes = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-8").GetBytes(accentedStr);
    return Encoding.UTF8.GetString(tempBytes, 0, tempBytes.Length);
}
```

Comment: It seems, this function turns Cyrillic symbols to question marks.

Comment: This is not a correct or wise solution. Converting to ISO-8859-8 and then to UTF-8 is not Unicode normalization.

Answer (score 0):

You will not find any alternative to String.Normalize in WinRT because it is available as part of the .NET Core Profile that is available to Metro style apps.  [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/8eaxk1x2.aspx).  If you are using C++, [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4884854/unicode-string-normalization-in-c-c).

Comment: I use C#, so this won't help much.