# Character encoding in programming with languages such as C

Tags: c, ascii, utf

Having read tutorials and books on C, I am trying hard to connect my knowledge of UTF (as the text format for roman letters and all sorts of other alphabets/scripts) with C, as a programming language used all over the world.

C seems to take ASCII characters.

So if I wanted to write a program with input/output in Chinese,say, how would I implement this with C?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would be using "wide char" `wchar` instead of `char`.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_character
http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/007908799/xsh/wchar.h.html
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242983(v=vs.60).aspx

There are also specialized libraries like [iconv](http://www.gnu.org/s/libiconv/) that help on some platforms.

Answer (score 1):

It's *character encoding*, not *text formatting*. If you want to use UTF in C, you can use a library to handle it (see e.g. here for UTF-8 libraries: [Light C Unicode Library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/313555/light-c-unicode-library)). If you're writing a GUI program, your GUI library probably has facilities to handle it (GTK, KDE, wxWidgets and Tk all support Unicode).