# Handling the utf8 encoded char* array

Tags: c++, unix, suncc

A file contains non-latin content and is encoded in UTF8.
Currently the existing code uses "`fopen`" to open the file, parses it and calls my `validate` function with the non-latin content and passes data as `char*`.

```
void validate(const char* str)
{
    ....
}
```

I have to do some validation on passed `char` array.

The application uses `Sun C++ 5.11` and which I think doesn't supports `unicode`. (I googled for unicode support on Sun C++ 5.11, I didn't get any proper pointers about the unicode support. So I wrote a simple program to check if Sun C++ supports unicode and the program didn't compile).

How do I do the validation on the input `char*`? Is it possible using `wchar_t`?

Comment: It all depends on what you mean by "validation"... How are you supposed to "validate" the text? What requirements do you have for building your function?

Comment: I have to validate the presence of special characters(requirement has some non latin chars to compare against such as 'Æ', 'Ð'), consecutive blanks.

Comment: Maybe [this old question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/313555/light-c-unicode-library) can help you?

Comment: I can't use third party library for security reasons...

Comment: Then you could use [`std::codecvt_utf8`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/locale/codecvt_utf8) to converse the text to UCS-4 (which is identical to UTF-32). Will that help?

Answer (score 1):

> The application uses `<compiler>` and which I think doesn't supports unicode

This isn't a problem. You only need compiler support for unicode to embed unicode string literals in the code, or for fixed width character types to represent UTF-16 or UTF-32. Your unicode is UTF-8 and comes from user input, so no unicode compiler support should be needed.

> How do I do the validation on the input `char*`?

The C++ standard library has very few tools for processing unicode. The provided tools primarily consist of conversion between different unicode formats, and even those tools were not available prior to C++11.

Input and output is mostly just copying of bytes, so no significant processing is required to do that. For other processing (which you presumably need for "validation") you will need to implement the tools yourself, or use third party tools. You will need to refer to the ~1000 pages of the unicode standard if you choose to implement yourself: http://www.unicode.org/versions/Unicode9.0.0/UnicodeStandard-9.0.pdf

> Is it possible using `wchar_t`?

`wchar_t` is the native wide character type used for the native wide character encoding of the system. UTF-8 does not use wide code-units.

Comment: I am planning to store the list of invalid chars in a text file and the encoding will be utf8. Then read the content to a char array and then do the validation against this array.